# Combining Excel UDF and Conditional Custom Data Validation in Data Entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

So based on research this might not be possible without the use of VBA code but nonetheless, I feel it is worth asking. I want to allow a user to only enter data into a cell if and only if the preceding adjacent is a specific value.

For instance, a have a drop down list in A1 with the following values; `Staff`, `Student`, `Manager`, `Board`. If the user selects `Staff`, `Student`, `Manager` in **A1**, then the value in **B1** is automatically generated using a **UDF** `IF` Formula but if the value selected in A1 is `Board`, then the user can enter a specific numerical value in **B1**.

Since custom Validation must return **TRUE** or **FALSE** there exists no formula that can be entered into the formula tab of the **custom data validation** window.

So is there a workaround where the formula can be entered in the cell and then the formula will not exist if the choice in **A1** is `Board`.

I hope this is fairly understandable.

If there isn't, can anyone help with some code construct to enable me to overcome this issue? As my VBA knowledge is still very amateur.

So from my knowledge I would believe a code in this sort of construct would apply;

`If Select Case Range(A1).Value = "Staff" Then
    B1 = Application.WorksheetFunction. (Since a Match function is employed)
 ElseIf Select Case Range(A1).Value = "Student" Then
    B1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.
 ElseIf Select Case Range(A1).Value = "Manager" Then
    B1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.
 ElseIf Select Case Range(A1).Value = "Board" Then 
   (My knowledge fails me here)
 Else
    B1 =""
 End If`

If possible I don't really want to employ the use of `InputBox`

Thank you for your response.

Comment: "but if the value selected in A1 is Board, then the user can enter a specific numerical value in B1" - no there is no way for that. This is one of the principle of Excel (and generally spreadsheet application): a cell may contain OR a user input constant value OR a formula, those can't be combined. "If there isn't, can anyone help with some code construct" - sorry, this isn't a free code writing service, we're happy to help with specific questions, but won't do your job instead of you.

Comment: @MátéJuhász - I don't disagree about not being a code writing service, but he did provide at least some pseudo-code, so I felt he'd made enough effort to do the google search on "vba excel lock cells" for him. ;)

Comment: @MátéJuhász - your point about a cell containing a value _or_ a formula is very valid.

Comment: @FreeMan: having some code doesn't mean OP has invested time writing it. His UDF is quite independent from his question, it needs to be solved through Worksheet's Change event.

Comment: Also a valid point. Guess I was feeling extra generous this morning...

Comment: @MátéJuhász by code construct I don't want you to help me write my code, where is the learning value in that? I did write some pseudo code. Where I state my knowledge fails in the code I would like a pointer to help me write this code so if the user selects `Board` then allow him to enter a value in B1. I know this can be achieved using `InputBox` but I wanted to see if I could not use this. Thanks for the clarification on the things a spreadsheet cell can contain and the rule governing them.

Comment: " where is the learning value in that?" - what do you mean by that? Tutorials? That's also off-topic here (see https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Writing pseudo-code is very far from actual solution and without stating your level of proficiency in VBA coding and presenting what you've achieved so far, our best guess is that you require us to do your job (or teach you coding from scratch, which is even bigger job).

Comment: If I have you do my Job, how would I learn the process of understanding how to solve my problem? I have stated my proficiency level of VBA in the question please feel free to peruse. My question was laid out clearly in different phases of which you answered the first part clearly the second part of the question asks if it is possible with VBA so if A1 = "Board" then clear contents of B1 and hence the user can enter the desired value. I am looking for written code. I have not asked a specific question about my problem again I am looking for pointers or directions or references.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm missing something, the UDF is written in VBA, so you've already got some code in your workbook.

Also, I presume your workbook is locked to prevent people from entering data in cells they're not supposed to.

Based on those assumptions, and cleaning up your pseudo-code somewhat, modify your existing UDF with a few additional lines of code:

```
Dim refCell as Range
refCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mySheet).Range("A1")
Dim targetCell as Range
targetCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mySheet).Range("B1")
With refCell
  If .Value = "Staff" or .Value = "Manager" or .Value = "Board" then
    targetCell.Locked = True
    'Call your existing UDF code here to generate the value
  Else
    targetCell.Locked = False
  End If
End With
```

That should get you started.

Comment: A UDF (VBA function called from the worksheet) cannot change other cells from which it's called.  ["A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot change the environment of Microsoft Excel."](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel). Where do you think your code should be placed to work?

Comment: @FreeMan Big thank you but the issue is not in the locking or unlocking of the cell it is in the combination of the user input and the formula at the same time.